# animation text function callback jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have problem here http://test10.bitballoon.com/
I have animation (show/hide) text.first text has class "active". the animation show this text then remove class "active" and add this class to the next text and callback the function again.. the function also check if the last text has class "active" then remove and add class "active" to the first text and hide all text and callback again. this how it work. the first time work fine when the animation finished callback again and animate the first text good then the function add "active" to multiple text then all text and function break. i don't know why this happen i tried to use setInterval but the same problem

```js
function animateText() {
    "use strict";        
    if ($(".text-container .active").hasClass("left")) {
        $(".text-container .active").addClass("active");
        $(".text-container .active").delay(1000).animate({
            marginLeft: 0,
            opacity: 1
        }, 700, function() {
            if ($(".text-container .text:last").hasClass("active")) {
                $(".text-container .text:last").removeClass("active")
                $(".text-container .text").animate({
                    opacity: 0
                }, 700, function() {
                    $(".text-container .text:first").addClass("active");
                    animateText();
                })
            }
            $(".text-container .active").removeClass("active").next().addClass("active");
            animateText();
        });
    } else if ($(".text-container .active").hasClass("right")) {
        $(".text-container .active").addClass("active");
        $(".text-container .active").delay(1000).animate({
            marginRight: "5px",
            opacity: 1
        }, 700, function() {
            if ($(".text-container .text:last").hasClass("active")) {
                $(".text-container .text:last").removeClass("active")
                $(".text-container .text").animate({
                    opacity: 0
                }, 700, function() {
                    $(".text-container .text:first").addClass("active");
                    animateText();
                })
            }
            $(".text-container .active").removeClass("active").next().addClass("active");
            animateText();
        });
    }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="text-container">
    <div class="text left active">
        <p>Hello World</p>
    </div>
    <div class="text left">
        <p>Hello World2</p>
    </div>
    <div class="text right">
        <p>Hello World3</p>
    </div>
    <div class="text right">
        <p>Hello World4</p>
    </div>
    <div class="text left">
        <p>Hello World5</p>
    </div>
    <div class="text right">
        <p>Hello World6</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: `if ($(".text-container .active").hasClass("left")) {...` none of the child divs has class `left`. When is this supposed to be true?

Comment: class left added before the animation function.. you can check  http://test10.bitballoon.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As long as this animation is concerned, there is no use for class `.active`. Note I added some css to accommodate it in the snippet, so let me know if it helps.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
                animateText($(".text-container .active"));
            });

            function animateText($this) {
                var leftParams = {'left': 0, opacity: 1};
                var rightParams = {'right': 0, opacity: 1};

                $this.stop(true).animate(
                        ($this.hasClass('left') ? leftParams : rightParams),
                        1000, function() {
                            if ($this.next().presence())
                                animateText($this.next());
                            else
                                startOver();
                        }
                );
            }

            function startOver() {
                var selector = $(".text-container .text");
                var next = $(".text-container > .active");
                selector.animate({
                    opacity: 0
                }, 200, function() {
                    selector.filter('.left').css('left', -200);
                    selector.filter('.right').css('right', -200);
                    animateText(next);
                });
            }

            $.fn.presence = function() {
                return this.length !== 0 && this;
            };
```

```css
.text-container {
 display: inline-block;
 width: 260.4px;
 height: 419px;
 
 
 padding-top: 10px;
 padding-left: 5px;
 overflow: hidden;
  
}

.text-container .text {
 max-width: 225px;
 float: left;
 padding: 8px 9px;
 margin-bottom: 6px;
 border-radius: 20px;
 text-align: left;
 background-color: rgba(224,230,237,.5);
 clear: both;
 opacity: 0;
  position: relative;
  
}

.text-container .left {
    float: left;
    left: -200px;
    
}

.text-container .right {
    float: right;
    right: -200px;
    background-color: #1bb45e;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="text-container">
    <div class="text left active">
        <p>Hello World</p>
    </div>
    <div class="text left">
        <p>Hello World2</p>
    </div>
    <div class="text right">
        <p>Hello World3</p>
    </div>
    <div class="text right">
        <p>Hello World4</p>
    </div>
    <div class="text left">
        <p>Hello World5</p>
    </div>
    <div class="text right">
        <p>Hello World6</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: thank you so much i really appreciate the effort you made.